# What is the best complexity of N-Queens puzzle?

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory, n-queens

Can the N-Queens puzzle theoretically be solved in polynomial time? If so, what is the best complexity of it? I have found many algorithms, but I haven't found what exactly the time complexity is. Are there any papers or documents giving an exact number of its complexity?

(P.S. The explicit solution is very interesting, but I forgot to say, I wish to find all the solutions.)

Answer (score 7):

This link cites a "well known" explicit solution. It can be computed in linear time:

http://www.chegg.com/homework-help/questions-and-answers/poor-man-s-n-queens-problemn-queens-arranged-n-x-n-chessboard-way-queen-checks-queen-queen-q1009394

> 1. n is even but not of the form (n mod 6 = 2).
>      Place queens on the squares
>      (m, 2m) and (n/2 +m, 2m-1) for m = 1, 2, . . . , n/2
> 2. n is even but not of the form (n mod 6 = 0) and
>      Place queens on the squares
>      (m, 1+(2(m-1)+ n/2 - 1)mod n) and
>      (n+1-m, n-(2(m-1)+n/2 -1)mod n) for m = 1,2,...,n/2
> 3. n is odd.
>      Use (1) or (2), whichever is appropriate, on n - 1 and extend with a queen at (n,n).

Note that enumerating all solutions would take much longer. The number of solutions grows super-exponentially with the size of the board (http://oeis.org/A000170), so they are impossible to enumerate even with `2^O(x)` time (but only `O(n)` space is needed).

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean finding one solution or all solutions? If you only want to find one solution, this can be done trivially, according to Wikipedia.

> Explicit solutions exist for placing n queens on an n × n board,
>   requiring no combinatorial search whatsoever.

Comment: The omitted wiki link: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eight_queens_puzzle#Explicit_solutions

Comment: Can you find the explicit solution? I tried and failed. The source WP references is cash-only, but I did see an explicit solution on the internet.

Comment: I'm sorry, I mean finding all solutions.